# error: stray ‘@’ in program and others with NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I've been trying to follow the Cool school Objective-C course and I'm stuck on challenge 10/11. It wants me to create an array variable and then access the values. Here is what it gave me:

```
NSArray *apps = @[@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot"];
NSLog (@"%@", apps[1]);
```

The online compiler throws out this:

```
main.m: In function ‘main’:
main.m:7:17: error: stray ‘@’ in program
 NSArray *apps = @[@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot"];
                 ^
main.m:7:31: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 NSArray *apps = @[@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot"];
                               ^
main.m:7:47: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
 NSArray *apps = @[@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot"];
                                               ^
main.m:7:62: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘]’ token
 NSArray *apps = @[@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot"];
                                                              ^
```

What could be my problem?

Comment: [Objective-C literals](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) are available since Apple LLVM Compiler 4.0 (AFAIR Xcode 6). They are apparently not supported by the online compiler.

Comment: Thank you!! pulled out the laptop and done it in xcode instead and it worked

Comment: For the online compiler you have to use classic `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot", nil];`

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with http://rextester.com/l/objectivec_online_compiler, I got the same error:

```
//gcc 5.0.4

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray *apps = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AngryFowl", @"Lettertouch", @"Tweetrobot", nil];
    NSLog (@"%@", [apps objectAtIndex:1]);
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

when i use

> arrayWithObjects

and

> objectAtIndex

it works：

```
2018-10-05 06:11:35.286 a.out[21957] Lettertouch
```